# nginx-ingress "Reading subject alternative from client certificate"

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Similar to how we can achieve to validate OID X509 in nginx conf, how do we achieve the same in nginx-ingress (via server-snippet or configuration snippet)

https://github.com/nginx/njs-examples#reading-subject-alternative-from-client-certificate-httpcertssubject_alternative